# How does the OpenGL render loop work and how to correctly count FPS?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, frame-rate

I tried to count the FPS in my render loop like this:

```cpp
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    float current = (float) glfwGetTime();
    delta = current - time;
    time = current;
    std::cout << 1.f / delta << std::endl;
    render();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

...with VSync enabled:

```cpp
glfwSwapInterval(1);
```

...but the output looks like this:

```
72.0857
345.182
73.3988
343.092
71.9065
375.564
71.9188
353.294
71.9324
360.212
72.3131
277.364
```

So it seems like roughly every second draw call is skipped. How can I check if the drawing was skipped in a frame so that I doesn't count it into the frame rate, what happens in these iterations and why are they skipped?

Comment: Using `std::cout` inside your render loop, especially if you're on Windows and even more so using `std::endl` is likely distorting your results

Comment: @AlanBirtles I normally only output the frame rate with ImGui but it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it appears to be something Apple broke on M1 MacBooks and there is already an attempt to fix it:

- [GLFW Issue #1834](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/1834)
- [GLFW Issue #2249](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/2249)
- [Pull request for possible solution](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/pull/2277)

As a temporary fix downgrading to GLFW 3.3 fixes VSync and the FPS counter so that the frame rate stays at stable 60.